# How to add only Jquery.UI.Autocomplete not Whole Library

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i am very new to .net, almost fresher in jquery, i want to add a autocomplete feature in a page i used Jquery.Ui library and its working fine, but my team leader asked me to not to use whole library and stylesheets since it is bigger in bytes(size) of this library but only something like Jquery.UI.Autocomplete only, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the download builder to customise the scripts to only what you need :

https://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, i have downloaded and included into application and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript and css should be written in a way that you can easily determine how to comment out the rest of the functionality and styles - then test that your autocomplete functionality still works.

If you are happy you can delete out the commented code and reduce the files size.

Answer (score 0):

got to http://jqueryui.com/download
then uncheck all except `Autocomplete`, then download the zip, the js will only contain autocomplete widget

Comment: Thank you so much Alan, i have done with Tom Answer and same Suggested by you, Thanks